# Google cloud container engine pod creation with two containers failing

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, kubectl

I'm trying to set up a wordpress instance that's using google cloud sql.
When i follow the instructions given here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-container-engine
using the yaml that's being provided here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-samples/tree/master/cloudsql
I just changed the port numbers as per instructions and added my own connection string to the yaml.

I get the following error when I try to create the deployment:

> Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for
>   pod wordpress-2460939176-g38lm, choose one of: [web cloudsql-proxy]

The pod somehow seems to have trouble understanding that it should two containers?

Any idea anybody?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying `kubectl logs` or `kubectl exec` ? Since there are multiple containers in your Pod, you need to specify the container too for the operation (`-c containername` option)

Comment: kubectl logs was indeed what i was trying, now that you say it, it does make a lot of sense - doh...
still getting a BadRequest error from the Server now:

'Error from server (BadRequest): container "cloudsql-proxy" in pod "carawordpress-2029542288-q3790" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating'

Comment: Try `kubectl describe pod` on it. Look at the events section too see why it's stuck in ContainerCreating

Comment: @JanosLenart Thanks, that set me up on the right path! Proxy container couldn't mount secret volume. Didn't know that `kubectl describe pod` shows errors, just used `kubectl logs` so far.